# Prevent video from downloading by Download Manager

Tags: video, video-streaming

I am using [Wowza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wowza_Media_Server) for live streaming. When streaming is done the recorded file of streamed video is stored in content folder. I set this video as VOD. The problem is that the video is downloaded by Download manager. I want to prevent it from downloading. Is there any way in Wowza to protect content folder video from downloading?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is a bit like creating a language which can only be spoken by Finnish people - as long as one application is able to download a file, every other application running in the same context *will* be able to download it as well. You can try to circumvent this in a myriad ways, such as detecting how the client identifies itself (easily spoofed), using a proprietary protocol (*much* more work for you *and* the end user), or even encryption built into the downloading client. However, even in the very worst case a download manager can simply emulate a user inside the client, and then you're just as far.